# Is there an easy way to store a reference to an arbitrary instance variable in an array?

Tags: iphone

I want to store instance variable references of aribrary objects in an array, so that I can iterate over the array and set these instance variables.

Would I have to provide their memory addresses to the array? like

```
[arr addObject:&anIvar];
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you can get an address of ivar and store it in NSArray by converting it to NSNumber. Still, it would be better to store a pair of values: target object and target property and use KVC to set them:

```
[myArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self, @"someProperty", nil]];
```

Acceccible with:

```
for(NSArray *pairs in myArray) {
    [[pairs objectAtIndex:0] setValue:myValue forKey:[pairs objectAtIndex:1]];
}
```

Comment: KVC is nice, but could I also have references to instance variables directly in the array?

Comment: Yes, as [NSNumber numberWithInt:&myivar]

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** (The old answer was based on misunderstanding the question.)

The easiest way to get a pointer to an instance variable is to use the get accessor, if it's present.  Example:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
  UIView* aView;  // Protected by default.
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView* aView;

// Elsewhere in the code..
MyClass* myClass = [self getThatObject];
UIView* viewOfMyClass = myClass.aView;
// You may now do what you wish with viewOfMyClass, which is a reference to
// myClass's aView object, including add it to an array for later use.
```

You can sometimes grab a pointer to an instance variable by thinking of the object as a struct.  Example:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
  @public
  UIView* aView;
}

// Later, in another part of the code...
MyClass* myClass = [self getThatObject];
UIView* viewOfMyClass = myClass->aView;
viewOfMyClass.tag = 100;  // Just changed myClass's aView's tag.
```

This works because `aView` is a public instance variable in `MyClass`.

If the instance variable you want to mess with is protected or private, and there's no accessor, then it's a little harder.  If it's your own class, you can just add an accessor.

If it's not your class, then this is a clear sign that you'd be breaking encapsulation if you used such a pointer.  So I wouldn't recommend it, but you could still achieve this goal with some clever casting.

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for. I want to store references to instance variables of any objects in an array, so that I can just iterate over all of them and set their values to something (I'll know what kind of value can be assigned).

Comment: Aha! I just realized the misunderstanding.

I think you want pointers to variables that are members of a class, probably from outside the class. I was confused because those are called in "member varables" in C++ land, where I grew up; and I'm just seeing now that "instance variables" means the same thing in Objective-C kingdom, or so it seems